# Is it possible to get the field value of user reference autocomplete from username?

Tags: 7, users

I am able to find the username. From the username I need to fill the user reference field.

Is there a way to get the user reference field value from username?

Example:

I have username: abc
I need Reference field value: Abc(201)

```
user_load_by_name('admin')

stdClass Object
(
    [uid] => 1
    [name] => admin
    [pass] => $S$DYk/jJiQjg07cciSAeU2EeP3XVMm/WhWHG19rA1iQf/FIqdOmY5p
    [mail] => test@gmail.com
    [theme] => 
    [signature] => 
    [signature_format] => 
    [created] => 1469189190
    [access] => 1511853833
    [login] => 1511853621
    [status] => 1
    [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
    [language] => 
    [picture] => 
    [init] => test@gmail.com
    [data] => 
    [uuid] => 77ef7473-31cd-432e-ace6-26f1b075abb5
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [2] => authenticated user
            [3] => administrator
        )

    [rdf_mapping] => Array
        (
            [rdftype] => Array
                (
                    [0] => sioc:UserAccount
                )

            [name] => Array
                (
                    [predicates] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => foaf:name
                        )

                )

            [homepage] => Array
                (
                    [predicates] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => foaf:page
                        )

                    [type] => rel
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Hmmm... It looks like you're not getting any fields.  If you run `$account = user_load_by_name($name); user_load($account->uid);`, does it give you the fields?  I don't think you should need to load the user twice though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [user_load_by_name($name)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load_by_name/7.x).

Once you load the user object you should be able to access the reference field normally.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick for quick reply. I have updated the question with the result of  user_load_by_name($name). Actually i am not getting the reference field value.